# Unable to find a region using the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder or setup environment to supply a region

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am using the AWS Java SDK v1 to access a Step Function.

Unfortunately I am getting this error about the region.

In my script file I defined like this.

```
private AWSStepFunctions client;
this.client = AWSStepFunctionsClientBuilder.defaultClient();
```

In application.properties I defined like this.

```
cloud.aws.region.static=eu-central-1
aws.region=eu-central-1
```

Comment: Since you're using `application.properties`, I'm assuming that you're using Spring in some form. Does it provide a way to create clients that use properties? If yes, then use that. If no, and you need to create clients explicitly, you'll need to provide credentials/region in one of the [AWS-supported ways](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/region-selection.html#automatically-determine-the-aws-region-from-the-environment).

Comment: you are right! Now it is necessary to build the client directly using this piece of code.
AWSStepFunctionsClientBuilder.standard().withRegion((Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1)).build()

Comment: I think it would make more sense to retrieve that region from the properties, or better, create a bean factory for your client. Otherwise, that will become a hard-to-find bug if you ever deploy outside the hardcoded region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you are using is an old API and no longer considered best practice. Amazon Strongly recommends using V2 over V1.

The way you are creating a service client is outdated too. To programmatically work with AWS Step Functions, consider using the recommended API - which is **AWS SDK for Java v2**.

To create an [AWS Step Functions Service Client](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/sfn/SfnClient.html) and specify the Region, use Java code like this:

```
 Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
 SfnClient sfnClient = SfnClient.builder()
           .region(region)
            .build();
```

See the [AWS Step Functions Readme](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/stepfunctions) here for more set up instructions for AWS SDK Java V2.